# Matlab: extract only odd columns from matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix NxN.

I want to extract values only from odd columns in this matrix.

http://photoload.ru/data/38/5d/d2/385dd20f148fd21a08de36a9c03e69a1.jpg

And after generate new matrix by this values.

How, I can do it?

Comment: Take a look at the colon operator: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/colon.html

Comment: Another suggestion is to lookup and download the MatLab User Guides. They are a great resource and can really help out a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

% data is NxN matrix

```
newData = data(:, 1:2:end);
```

%The 1:2:end says start with first column, skip every other until end

Comment: You’re welcome. The colon operator is a great feature of matlab syntax. Once you learn to use it it’ll treat you well.